# How to ignore specific workbook in folder using VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that let me select the folder I want and then I have a loop on it which opens all excel files in it but I want to exclude this workbook (Dummy.xlsm). Is it possible to not read that file while looping through the folder?

Here's the code. Thank very much!

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ValueRow As Integer
Dim ValueColumn As Integer
Dim LookupValue As Variant
Dim ValueAtColumn1 As Variant
Dim ValueAtColumn2 As Variant
Dim ValueAtColumn3 As Variant
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim cel As Range
Dim arrayString() As String
Dim ppmString() As String
Dim StrFile As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

myExtension = "*.xls*"
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

Do While myFile <> ""
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=myPath & myFile)
ValueRow = 4
Sheets("Template").Range("A4:IX200").ClearContents

DoEvents

For Each ws In Sheets
Select Case ws.Name
Case Is = "Summary", "Count", "Table", "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Template", "Template(2)", "Control", "Generated_data_2", "Fleet Data"
Case Else
ws.Range("C3").Copy Worksheets("Template").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
For i = 4 To 6
    Worksheets("Template").Cells(ValueRow, i).Value = ws.Range(Worksheets("Template").Cells(3, i).Value).Value
Next i

Next ws

wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
DoEvents
myFile = Dir
Loop
MsgBox "Done!"

ResetSettings:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `If` statement around all the code you want not to run that checks what the filename is like this:

```
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

Do While myFile <> ""
  If myFile <> "Dummy.xlsm" Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=myPath & myFile)

    ' the rest of the code here

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True    
  End If
  myFile = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please remember to close the question using the green checkmark to the left of my answer. :)